# Facing an error while harmonizing the data

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am new to MLDataHubFramework,started to create a new entity flow by following the marklogic documentation.
1. Created Customer entity and ingested to staging database.
2. While trying to perform the harmonization am getting the below issue.

**ERROR Output:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: failed to apply resource at resources/ml:sjsFlow: Internal Server Error. Server Message: TDE-INDEX: xdmp:eval("xdmp.docume
ntInsert(\"/12545362905389506919.json\",trace,xdmp.de...", {trace:{trace:{jobId:"38b8a84d-7927-4aac-a482-33d64a9cf56e", format:"json", traceId:"12545362905389506919", ...}}}, {database:"3883525708217113046", co
mmit:"auto", update:"true", ...}) -- Error applying template /tde/Customer-0.0.1.tdex to document /12545362905389506919.json: TDE-EVALFAILED: Eval for $subject-iri='sem:iri(concat("http://example.com/Customer-0
.0.1/Customer/", fn:encode-for-uri(./CustomerId)))' returns TDE-BADVALEXPRESSION: Invalid val expression: XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) arg1 is not of type xs:string? . See the MarkLogic server error log for fur
ther detail.
```

But here I have defined the CustomerId as string.I tried with multiple entities and getting same issue for all.
Can anyone suggest me what goes wrong? I have cross verified the TDE files and other stuff(schema,entity json,xsd) as well but didn't see any issue at ll in those files.

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic is saying that when it applied this TDE template to the new document, it got a value that didn't fit.

> Error applying template /tde/Customer-0.0.1.tdex to document /12545362905389506919.json: TDE-EVALFAILED: Eval for $subject-iri='sem:iri(concat("http://example.com/Customer-0
>   .0.1/Customer/", fn:encode-for-uri(./CustomerId)))' returns TDE-BADVALEXPRESSION: Invalid val expression: XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) arg1 is not of type xs:string?

Try this:

- get the content of your new document in a variable
- use your "context" from the template against that document
- use `./CustomerId` and see what you get

Something like:

```
let $doc := document { <envelope... /> }
let $context := $doc/my/context/path
return $context/CustomerId
```

I'm wondering whether you might be returning more than one CustomerId, which would fit the error message.

If that doesn't do it, I encourage you to update your question with minimal versions of your document and your template needed to recreate the error. With that information, it should be a lot easier to spot the problem.